# Can I insert .jpeg and .gif images in my Vim files?

Tags: vim

Well I am new in Vim. So learning while working using Vim. I am currently learning Kivy (A Python framework) and taking some notes using Vim. However sometimes I need to save pictures (like .jpeg, .bmp etc.) and animations (like .gif) in my notebook. But the problem is after spending 15 minutes in Google I did not get any good answer to whether I can insert pictures and animations to my Vim documents or not? If I can insert then how can I do so? Can anyone let me know if there is any way to do?

**So why you should insert .gif images?**

You can see this .gif image (http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.anchorlayout). It gives much better idea than reading tons of words. I just want to save .gif images like this. I know I can download and play these images using IE. Also I can create links from my Vim document to the file to play it using IE. But I think the most convenient way would be inserting the file inside of my notebook(i.e. my Vim file).

Answer (score 6):

I hope to complete other answer with more existing solutions.

## Emacs way

Maybe emacs allows that you want : it allows  to show images in buffer and to play animation, (M-x find-file RET ~/example.gif RET image-toggle-animate).
In org-mode you can add image in your note and then open it aside, and animate (this scriptable).

## Vim way

As said, Vim is just a text editor it can only show and color text.
(this part feel like i'm doing my auto-promotion)

You can embed poor qualities images  (pixel art 16 colors 80x80 pixel with a 1ppi resolution) in text files with [Vim-Supertxt](https://github.com/luffah/vim-supertxt).

For the case of taking notes, i proceed with [Vim-Zim](https://github.com/luffah/vim-zim) that i configured to open image with `feh` (a small picture viewer) or `gifview -a` (animated gif viewer) using the keybinding `<Leader><Tab>`. Alternatively you could use `zim --server Notes` to render the notes on a local webserver (`localhost:8080`).

## Zim way

Zim is a personal wiki which could do what you want.

But to see animated GIF you shall insert image (check  option 'import image in note') and then start a local web server with Zim.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Vim is a text editor; as such it only deals with raw text and is not capable of embedding images or sound files or whatever.

You should try something like EverNote or OneNote instead.

Comment: Well then I can try MSWord as I am familiar to it. But don't you think any plugin can do the job?

Comment: @Hellboy no plugin will be able to do that. Check [Vim FAQ 1.1](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-1.1).

Comment: @Hellboy, no any plugin can only do, what Vim supports. There is no possibility to add new features, that Vim does not support. If you want images, then keep using a word processor

Comment: Alternatively, one can extend gVim. Vim is open-source. Displaying an image is one of the easiest tasks in the hello world.

Answer (score 1):

@romainl is right, but I want to give his answer a different spin.

Vim supports editing a vast set of different *file types*. Though it can open binary files (which most images are encoded in), it is predominantly used to edit *text* files. That's where Vim's editing capabilities shine and enable very efficient editing.

So, though many file formats are *edited* by programmers and technical people inside Vim, most of them are meant to be *consumed* by another application: Python scripts are executed by the Python interpreter, HTML is viewed in the browser, Markdown may be transformed into another format.

#### Conclusion

Keeping a notebook is a good practice, and you certainly can use Vim to efficiently maintain it. However, if you have a need for including graphics (and elaborate formatting like headers in different font sizes etc.), Vim will only support you with the *editing* part, the *viewing* has to be done in a different application. (But that's okay and quite common, as I've outlined.)

For the format, there are many possibilities: HTML, Markdown, or any kind of Wiki (which are mostly browser-based, but you can integrate Vim with browser editing, e.g. via the *Pentadacyl* addon for Firefox).

If this feels too complex for you, better stick with one of the mentioned all-in-one alternatives like MS Word or OneNote.

Answer (score 1):

since 16 october 2015 is possible convert *.jpg/*.png in ASCII
https://github.com/ashisha/image.vim

python required.

does exists also thumbnail.vim: https://github.com/vim-scripts/thumbnail.vim but i don't know how to use this. Maybe it requires building?

Have fun!

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment on your post.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: This names a couple of tools but doesn’t answer how to accomplish what was asked.  Also, external links can become unavailable, in which case the answer would have no value.  Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/150988)

Comment: @fixer1234: I see you also have a library of canned comments.  You might want to be a bit more careful with it; I don't know of any browser that recognizes `http://%24siteurl%24/…`.

Comment: @Scott: Glad you spotted that.  I had problems for a few days with the SE Auto-Comment add-in.  It uses that variable and normally substitutes an actual URL.  I didn't think to check it because it normally works, and the bad "link" is formatted like a real one.  I should probably just edit those placeholders to hard-code the link.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234: Ah, so you've gone high-tech.  I'm a caveman; I just have a document from which I copy and paste.  :-)  ⁠